# Django - trying to clean email field is throwing ''dict' object has no attribute 'strip'"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Halfway through my project I realized that I am able to create an account using the same email address. This will definitely create some problems later (recovering account, etc).

So I came up with the idea to clean the email field by testing to see if an account is already registered in the database by searching for the email.

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-sm'}))
    ...


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = {'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'}


def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email is already registered")
    return self.cleaned_data
```

This should be able to solve the problem, but it is throwing the

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I also made sure to set the cleaned email in the function.

Here is my register method:

```
def register(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('somewhere')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid():
                # begin google reCaptcha validation
                recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
                url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
                values = {
                    'secret': GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
                    'response': recaptcha_response
                }
                data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode()
                req =  urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)
                response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
                result = json.loads(response.read().decode()) # end of reCaptcha validation

                if result['success']:
                    # create a new user but avoid saving it yet
                    new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                    new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
new_user.set_email(user_form.cleaned_data['email'])
                    new_user.save()
                    # automatically create a profile of new user
                    Profile.objects.create(
                        user=new_user,
                        ... )
                    messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully')
                    return render(request, 'account/register_done.html', {'new_user':new_user})
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
        else:
            user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

Here is traceback:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/register/

Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.7.0


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\\MyVenv\\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\\MyVenv\\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\\MyVenv\\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\\\\account\views.py" in register
  60.             if user_form.is_valid():

File "C:\Users\\MyVenv\\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  185.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "C:\Users\\MyVenv\\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  180.             self.full_clean()

File "C:\Users\\MyVenv\\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  383.         self._post_clean()

File "C:\Users\\MyVenv\\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _post_clean
  403.             self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)

File "C:\Users\\MyVenv\\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in full_clean
  1137.             self.clean()

File "C:\Users\\MyVenv\\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py" in clean
  338.         self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)

File "C:\Users\\MyVenv\\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py" in normalize_email
  25.             email_name, domain_part = email.strip().rsplit('@', 1)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /account/register/
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Can you please explain what is going on, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `clean_email` method should be returning the email value, not the entire cleaned_data dict.

```
def clean_email(self):
    ...
    return email
```

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way to do this would be to use an EmailField in your User model if you created a custom one:

```
    ...
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True) # default User model doesn't have unique=True
    ...
```

The unique=True will check to make sure that the same email doesn't already exist in the database.

It comes with a default error, but you can still use your custom one:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email is already registered")
    return self.cleaned_data
```

That might take care of the "dict' object has no attribute 'strip'" error on its own.

Also, the problem could be the way you are setting the email. Instead of:

```
new_user.set_email(user_form.cleaned_data['email'])
new_user.save()
```

Try:

```
new_user.email = user_form.cleaned_data['email'])
new_user.save()
```

I'm not sure exactly what the set_email function is doing.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. From my understanding, forms do not have a unique field. I tried using an forms.EmailField(), but the problem still unfortunately remains.

Comment: @Mike - ah sorry, I meant in your model, but I just realized you didn't post your model and I don't know if you inherited from Django auth and created your own User model.